# Implementing COM (exposed by .NET/C#) interface in Ruby

Tags: .net, ruby, com, win32ole

I would like to implement in Ruby such interface (snipped in .NET):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    public interface Name
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        string Definition { get; }
        [ComVisible(true)]
        void SetId(int databeseID);
    }
```

using WIN32OLE methods from win32ole library for ruby. 
So I can then for example assign my implementing object to a property of another com object, implementation in C# itself. Do not need to explain to me everything from scratch, only this, as I already have been working with the Ruby-Com-.NET architecture for a couple of weeks.

```
 [ComVisible(true)]
         public interface Something
         {
             [ComVisible(true)]
             Name MName { get; }
         }
```

Please, I am not interested in IronRuby.